# Is bigger capacity ram faster then smaller capacity ram for same clock and CL?

Tags: memory, benchmarking

I know that bigger capacity hard-drives with the same RPM are faster then smaller capacity hard-drives. I was wondering if the same is true for ram. Given two ram clocked at 1600mhz and with identical CLs: 9-9-9-24. Is a 2x8 going to perform better then a 2x4 ?

Note that I am not asking if having more ram will improve the performance of my PC, I'm asking if the bigger capacity ram performs better.

Thank You.

Comment: Actually, I don't get how bigger HDDs are faster either. Its more a matter of things like number of platters and such.

Comment: I suspect this is an HDD assumption based on 1) "same RPM, larger physical platters". Which have a larger radius and thus more magnetic material passes beneath the heads per rotation. 2) Larger capacity as drives with higher density per surface unit.

Comment: @didibus: Assuming the same munber of ranks: no difference.

Comment: I had heard that since you cram more information on the platter, by packing them closer to each other, same as bluerays, you get speed boosts, because if you turn at the same rate, you are actually going over way more data, thus reading more of it. Maybe I'm wrong about hard-drives, and what I heard was false, but my question remains open for RAM.

Answer (score 0):

didbus is correct on the hard drive part; but as for ram, if it has the same number of ranks it will be the same speed. i.e. if a 4gb stick is made up of 4x1gb chips or an 8gb is made up of 8x1gb chips; the 8gb one will be faster. However if the 8gb one was 4x2gb chips it would be the same speed as 4x1gb.